# Jasmine spied object mock method return is not being overrided

Tags: angular, testing, mocking, jasmine, karma-runner

I have this global beforeEach, in which I define some serviceMocks with their returning value. In this case, generally I want to return the product with name "Prod1".

```
beforeEach(async(() => {

    //MOCKS
    let plansPrices:{[name:string]:number} = {["M"]:2, ["D"]:0.5};
    let prod:Product = {name: "Prod1", licenses:[], typeSubs:["M","D"],photoAvailable:false,description: "The description",webLink:"www.c.com",photoSrc:"",plansPrices:plansPrices,sku:null, active:true, trialDays:9, mode:"Both"};

    productServiceMock = jasmine.createSpyObj("ProductService", ["getProduct"]);
    productServiceMock.getProduct.and.returnValue(of(prod));


    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ CatalogProductComponent ,CardFormComponent ],
      imports: [ ReactiveFormsModule,MatGridListModule,MatIconModule,MatCardModule, MatSelectModule,MatOptionModule,NgxPaginationModule, MatSnackBarModule,HttpClientModule, FormsModule ],
      providers: [
        { provide: ProductService, useValue:productServiceMock },
           ...
      ]

    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));


beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CatalogProductComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    domHelper = new DOMHelper(fixture);
});
```

But in a specific test, I want to override that returning value, returning a product with name "Prod2". This is the test:

```
 it('should subscribe to free trial', () => {
    let plansPrices:{[name:string]:number} = {["M"]:2, ["D"]:0.5};
    let prod2:Product = {name: "Prod2", licenses:[], typeSubs:["M","D"],photoAvailable:false,description: "The description",webLink:"www.c.com",photoSrc:"",plansPrices:plansPrices,sku:null, active:true, trialDays:9, mode:"Both"};


    productServiceMock.getProduct.and.returnValue(of(prod2)); //Seems that this isn't working
    fixture.detectChanges(); //Calls the 

    let prodName = domHelper.getText("#productName");//Gets the text of an <a id="productName></a> setted on ngOnInit()

    expect(prodName).toBe("Prod2");  //This is failing, prodName is "Prod1"
});
```

Why it is still returning the value setted on the beforeEach, instead of being overrided by the statement made on the specific test?

Thank you

Comment: Please also share the code of the component in question. I assume the `getProduct` call you want to mock is being called "before" the actual mocking takes place.

Comment: @PhilippMeissner You made me think about it, and I came into the problem: getProduct was being called by the constructor and not by the ngOnInit.  Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, that's a common issue people run into. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding below line as you did in before each 
    productServiceMock = jasmine.createSpyObj("ProductService", ["getProduct"]);
 above  this one
 productServiceMock.getProduct.and.returnValue(of(prod2));.

As i guess you need to spy again before you need a new return value.